# Spin button and textbox in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, increment

I am trying to create a spin button that increases/decreases the quantity amount in a textbox. I was able to successfully created this but I also want to be able to type in the quantity amount I want on in the text box. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Here is what I did following instructions from a site:

Spin button: **sbtnQty**

Textbox: **txtQty**

```
Private Sub SbtnQty_Change()
  txtQty.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Finally, I went to txtQty's property and set the control source to: **=[sbtnQty]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the source to the table field `SpnQnty` and then change the value of the box with the buttons like this:

```
Sub ArrowUp_Click
    txtQty.Value = txtQty.Value + 1
End Sub
```